# How to deserialize a json array followed by a normal property into a pojo in jackson. The array alone works

Tags: java, json, jackson

The difficulty is, that the json labels are partly dynamic in the rest response of the Kraken api. At first I introduce a working case. I connect the Kraken trading api to fetch currencies as assets and got the following result in json.

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "AAVE": {
            "aclass": "currency",
            "altname": "AAVE",
            "decimals": 10,
            "display_decimals": 5
        },
        "ZUSD": {
            "aclass": "currency",
            "altname": "USD",
            "decimals": 4,
            "display_decimals": 2
        }
    }
}
```

AAVA and ZUSD in this example are dynamic labels. I use the embedded Jackson to parse it in the OpenFeign framework. The result part are covered with the following generic class:

```
public class Response<T> {
    
    private List<String> error = new ArrayList<>();
    private T result;
    
    // getter and setters
}
```

And as root class for the assets, the dynamic labels AAVA and ZUSD are handled by a Map:

```
public class AssetInfoResponse extends 
              Response<Map<String, AssetInfo>> {
}
```

The pojo AssetInfo:

```
public class AssetInfo implements Serializable{

    @JsonProperty("altname")
    private String alternateName;

    @JsonProperty("aclass")
    private String assetClass;

    @JsonProperty("decimals")
    private Byte decimals;

    @JsonProperty("display_decimals")
    private Byte displayDecimals;

    // getters, setters ...
}
```

The above case works perfectly, also the solution with the dynamic labels.

Here is the response with the ohlc data, that looks similar and I have no Idea to solve the deserialization problem in the next case:

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "XXBTZEUR": [
            [
                1613212500,
                "39000.1",
                "39010.1",
                "38972.3",
                "38994.1",
                "38998.1",
                "3.23811638",
                70
            ],
            [
                1613212560,
                "38994.3",
                "39014.5",
                "38994.3",
                "39014.5",
                "38997.3",
                "0.95105956",
                11
            ]
        ],
        "last": 1613212500
    }
}
```

The cause of the problem is the `"last": 1613212500` property line. When I remove this line, the response can be parsed without problems. I try to solve it with the following classes, `Response` is the upper described class.

```
public class OhlcLastResponse<T> extends Response<T> {

    private Long last;
   
    // getters and setters

}
```

The next class extends the prevourious class and is the root class for the objectmapper:

```
public class OhlcResponse
      extends OhlcLastResponse<Map<String, List<Candelstick>>> {
}
```

And the pojo that holds the candlestick data:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "time", "open", "high", "low",
                     "close", "vwap", "volume", "count" })
public class Candelstick implements Serializable {
    
    private Integer time;

    private BigDecimal open;

    private BigDecimal high;

    private BigDecimal low;

    private BigDecimal close;

    private BigDecimal vwap;

    private BigDecimal volume;

    private Integer count;

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

and here is the error:

```
                "38997.3",
                "0.95105956",
                11
            ]
        ],
        "last": 1613212500
    }
}
"; line: 26, column: 11] (through reference chain: OhlcResponse["result"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["last"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
```

Jackson tries to put the `last` property into the map, but the map was finished by `],`. Line 26 is the line  with the
`last` label in the json file.

Is there a possibility to parse this json? I think it must be possible, because the array is closed by the square bracket.

I hosted the rest client on [github](https://github.com/joe-bookwood/kraken-feign-rest-client). To reproduce the error just clone it and run `mvn test`.

Comment: do you want to map last field or you want to ignore?

Comment: I need the last field, because I need the value for the next rest call.

Comment: Well there is nothing out of the box for your use-case. You could have used `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` to parse the `last` value into a `Candlestick` object but therefore the `last` item must have been itself already in a list, key and value. So I think you have to end up with a thin and [custom deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization#on-mapper) to distinguish between the single `last` item and your list of `Candlestick`s.

Comment: Well the JSON you've posted is perfectly valid, yet not easily to parse in a type-safe manner but otherwise valid. Good luck!

Comment: Thx, the deserializer now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a deserializer, because the type handling is very difficult in this case. The deserializer decide between the two cases, array or the single last value, and call in the case of an array the deserializer for the `CandleStick` Class:

```
public class OhlcDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OhclPayload> {

    @Override
    public OhclPayload deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        List<CandleStick> candleSticks = new ArrayList<CandleStick>();

        Long last = null;

        ObjectCodec objectCodec = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectCodec.readTree(p);

        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> payloadIterator = jsonNode.fields();
        while (payloadIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = payloadIterator.next();
            if (entry.getKey().equals("last")) {
                last = entry.getValue().asLong();
            } else if (entry.getValue().isArray()) {
                for (JsonNode node : entry.getValue()) {
                    CandleStick cs = p.getCodec().treeToValue(node, CandleStick.class);
                    candleSticks.add(cs);
                }
            }
        }

        return new OhclPayload(candleSticks, last);
    }

}
```

I changed the OhclResponse to:

```
public class OhlcResponse extends Response<OhclPayload> {
}
```

And insert a OhlcPayload class for the deserializer:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = OhlcDeserializer.class)
public class OhclPayload {

    private List<CandleStick> candleSticks;

    private Long last;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Thats all.