# How to deserialize JSON array into type-safe c# class instance

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization, kraken.com

this question is almost identical to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190994/how-to-deserialize-a-json-array-followed-by-a-normal-property-into-a-pojo-in-jac)

I have tried translating the answer into C#, but I am not an expert in JSON and am a little lost.

I am attempting to deserialize this JSON response from the Kraken OHLC endpoint. [Example response, click here](https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=AAVEEUR&interval=1440&since=1679874582)

The request pulls back this JSON:

```
{
"error":[],

"result":
        {
            "XXBTZEUR":
                    [
                        [1679269500,"26401.1","26401.1","26211.6","26243.9","26307.1","8.92959425",311],
                        [1679270400,"26253.1","26324.7","26060.2","26242.9","26212.0","33.15872129",520],
                        [1679271300,"26250.1","26276.8","26216.8","26260.4","26259.0","3.63710383",183]
                    ],
                
            "last":1679915700

        }}
```

It's valid JSON, but I cannot figure out how to handle the "last" field, which seems to throw everything out.

I thought I was close with these Class structures, but no matter what, my inner array returns as null:

```
public class OHLCResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
    public List<string> Error;

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public OHLC Result { get; set; }
}

public class OHLC
{
    //[JsonProperty("ohlc_pairs")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<OHLCPair>> OHLCPairs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last")]
    public int Last { get; set; }
}

public class OHLCPair 
{
    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public int UnixDateStamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("high")]
    public string High { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("vwap")]                  //volume weighted average price
    public string VWAP { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public string Count { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm just calling it with a standard library that is happily handling most of the other objects into type-safe Classes in their API:

```
OHLCResponse cOHLCResponse = _CKraken.GetPublicWebResponse<OHLCResponse>("OHLC", param);
```

... which implements:

```
result = (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

The result, no matter how I  try to alter my type Classes is always an empty array, because I think that it just cannot handle the "last" field:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I was unfortunately not able to translate the custom deserializer in the previous question. Many thanks in advance, Dave.

Comment: Good spot. That's my "Notepad" version to try to figure out how it looks. I will correct the example, thanks.

Comment: You might want to parse into a `JObject` - most likely you're going to need to make a custom serializer to correctly map this data.

Comment: Yes. I mean, I can manually parse it, it's just text, but I was hoping there was something simpler that I'm doing wrong with my code! I actually don't need the "last" field, so clumsily I could always delete it from the text before parsing. I think it should then parse.

Comment: So the problem is you'd need to have a property `public Dictionary<string, object> Result` on the `OHLCResponse` class, where the Value is _either_ an `int` _or an array. Then, if it's an array, you'd need to match up each array index with the appropriate "friendly name" (time, open, high, etc). This already sounds very messy to do with a single Strongly Typed C# class.

Answer (score 3):

*Wow, quite a challenging question.*

I think you can achieve this by implementing the custom JSON converter for the `OHLC` and `OHLCPair` classes.

1. Register the `JsonConverter` with the `JsonConverter` attribute for the respective property.

```cs
public class OHLCResponse
{   
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
    public List<string> Error;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(OHLCConverter))]
    public OHLC Result { get; set; }
}

public class OHLC
{
    public OHLC() { }
        
    [JsonProperty("ohlc_pairs")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<OHLCPair>> OHLCPairs { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last")]
    public long Last { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(OHLCPairConverter))]
public class OHLCPair 
{
    public OHLCPair() { }

    
    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public long UnixDateStamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("high")]
    public string High { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("vwap")]                  //volume weighted average price
    public string VWAP { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

2. 

- In `OHLCPairConverter`, it aims to convert the key-value pair other than the `last` field to `Dictionary<string, List<OHLCPair>>` and assign it to the `OHLCPairs` property.
- In `OHLCPairConverter`, it aims to convert the array (`JArray`) with multiple values and types to an `OHLCPair` instance.

```cs
public class OHLCConverter : JsonConverter<OHLC>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, OHLC value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = serializer.Converters.Where(s => !(s is OHLCConverter)).ToList(),
            DateFormatHandling = serializer.DateFormatHandling,
            MissingMemberHandling = serializer.MissingMemberHandling,
            NullValueHandling = serializer.NullValueHandling,
            Formatting = serializer.Formatting
        };
        var localSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
        
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in typeof(OHLC).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty))
        {
            var jsonPropAttr = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            var propName = jsonPropAttr != null
                ? jsonPropAttr.PropertyName
                : propInfo.Name;
                
            writer.WritePropertyName(propName);
            
            if (propInfo.Name == "OHLCPairs")
            {
                var jObject = JObject.FromObject(propInfo.GetValue(value), localSerializer);
                jObject.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteValue(propInfo.GetValue(value));
            }
        }
        
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override OHLC ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, OHLC existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(token);
        Dictionary<string, List<OHLCPair>> ohlcPairs = null;
        
        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
        {
                ohlcPairs = obj.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()
                        .Where(x => x.Key != "last")
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                                      x => JArray.FromObject(x.Value)
                                        .Children<JArray>()
                                        .Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OHLCPair>(x.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings
                                                                   {
                                                                        Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new OHLCPairConverter() }   
                                                                   }))
                                        .ToList());
        }
    
        return new OHLC
        {
            OHLCPairs = ohlcPairs,
            Last = obj["last"].ToObject<int>()
        };
    }
}

public class OHLCPairConverter : JsonConverter<OHLCPair>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, OHLCPair value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in typeof(OHLCPair).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty))
        {
            var jsonPropAttr = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            var propName = jsonPropAttr != null
                ? jsonPropAttr.PropertyName
                : propInfo.Name;
                
            writer.WritePropertyName(propName);
            writer.WriteValue(propInfo.GetValue(value));
        }
                
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override OHLCPair ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, OHLCPair existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        JArray jArray = JArray.FromObject(token);
        
        return new OHLCPair
        {
            UnixDateStamp = jArray[0].ToObject<int>(),
            Open = jArray[1].ToObject<string>(),
            High = jArray[2].ToObject<string>(),
            Low = jArray[3].ToObject<string>(),
            Close = jArray[4].ToObject<string>(),
            VWAP = jArray[5].ToObject<string>(),
            Volume = jArray[6].ToObject<string>(),
            Count = jArray[7].ToObject<int>()
        };
    }
}
```

Anyway, for the `WriteJson` methods, you can achieve to write JSON (serialize) by deciding the format, the property, and its value to be printed without the need of *System.Reflection*. My approach seems to over-complicated.

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ddrbRA)

Comment: Wow, many thanks for taking the time to look at this and provide such a detailed explanation. I tried putting all this in a separate .cs file using the code you have  posted up at .NET Fiddle, but unfortunately, I cannot get it to compile. I am using MS Visual Studio 2019 with the latest version of JSON installed. I have made sure that I am using exactly the "using" references that you have in the example.  Screen grab of errors here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6ajkqp8c8zkht9/ohlc_example_errors.png?dl=0

Comment: May I know which Newtonsoft.Json version you used? And hover over the word `JsonConverter` to see which it comes from which namespace. Make sure that you **don't use** the one from [*System.Text.Json*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. This screen grab here answers your questions, I look forward to your response: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbqdi9ex8sx2jhs/JSON.png?dl=0

Comment: Your *Newtonsoft.Json* is quite old version. The generic `JsonConverter` only supports from [11.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1). Install the latest version or 11.0.1 and above.

Comment: For some reason, the "Nuget Package Manager" in MS VS 2019 only offersv9 as an option. I changed the Package folder to be a local folder on my computer, downloaded v11.0.1 from the web, and installed it. This immediately removed all the errors. I have now tested your code and it works perfectly. I really appreciate your time andI have upvoted your solution!

Answer (score 1):

you just need a very simple converter

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

OHLCResponse oHLCResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OHLCResponse>(json, new OHLCConverter());
    
public class OHLCConverter : JsonConverter<OHLCResponse>
{
    public override OHLCResponse ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, OHLCResponse existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var props = ((JObject)jObj["result"]).Properties().ToArray();
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<OHLCPair>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            var prop = props[i];
            if (prop.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array) continue;

            var arr = new JArray( prop.Value.Select(v => new JObject(
                     v.Select((x, index) => new JProperty(index.ToString(),x)))) );
                                
            dict.Add(prop.Name, arr.ToObject<List<OHLCPair>>());
            prop.Remove();
        }
        OHLCResponse oHLCResponse = jObj.ToObject<OHLCResponse>();
        oHLCResponse.Result.OHLCPairs = dict;
        return oHLCResponse;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, OHLCResponse value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and change JsonProperty attributes of OHLCPair class

```
public class OHLCPair
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public int UnixDateStamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string Open { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2")]
    public string High { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3")]
    public string Low { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4")]
    public string Close { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("5")]
    public string VWAP { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("6")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("7")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This looks fantastic. I have tried it out, but I cannot get it to compile unfortunately. I am using MS VS 2019, and have the latest version of JSON installed via NuGet. There are four errors with the class "public class OHLCConverter : JsonConverter<OHLCResponse>".

Comment: Error CS0534 'OHLCConverter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'JsonConverter<OHLCResponse>.Read(ref Utf8JsonReader, Type, JsonSerializerOptions)'
Error CS0534 'OHLCConverter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'JsonConverter<OHLCResponse>.Write(Utf8JsonWriter, OHLCResponse, JsonSerializerOptions)'
Error CS0115 'OHLCConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader, Type, OHLCResponse, bool, JsonSerializer)': no suitable method found to override
Error CS0115 'OHLCConverter.WriteJson(JsonWriter, OHLCResponse, JsonSerializer)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: @DavyC as you understand I test all my code before posting. This code was tested too and working properly. Don't try to adapt this code to yours. Just copy the whole code as it is.

Comment: @DavyC Another option is to  select from Visual Studio  "implement abstract class", and after implementing this delete all code inside of ReadJson and copy this code from inside of ReadJson

Comment: many thanks for your response. The problem was that I had v9 of JSON installed. For some reason, the "Nuget Package Manager" in MS VS 2019 only offers v9 as an option. I changed the Package folder to be a local folder on my computer, downloaded v11.0.1 from the web, and installed it. This immediately removed all the errors. I have now tested your code and it works perfectly. I really appreciate your time andI have upvoted your solution!